# How to test passing Intent data to InstantApp

Tags: google-play, deep-linking, google-play-console, android-instant-apps

I have an InstantApp that initiates and executes fine in Internal Testing in the Play Console. For distribution it needs to be initiated by a URL that includes at least one query term that is handled as Intent data, e.g., https://com.domain/?q=1234567. The code for parsing and applying the data term ("1234567") works perfectly to initiate an Intent when I test a configuration in AS Giraffe w/ a cabled device.

Internal Testing does not handle this kind of URL. Clicking a URL like https://play.google.com/testing/packageName only executes the package; it does not transfer data.

I have tried with a Closed test and an example URL fixed in the code which works fine. Now I need to test the URL above. I have studied all the suggested Similar Answers, but they all deal with passing data between Activities. This is specifically about passing data to an Instant App. I believe such a URL is supposed to work as a released product (otherwise testing a URL in AS wouldn't work), but I want to test in advance.

Is there any way I can do this in a Closed Test? If I promote to an Open Test, will that work?

Thanks in advance.